# Getting AbstractType from request

Tags: symfony, controller, abstract-type

The user sumbits a form that was build using the symfony 2 framework with abstract type:

```
<?php
$form = $this->createForm(new MyAbstractType(), new MyEntity());
```

I receive this post request in an action:

```
public function receiveFormRequestAction(Request $request){
    //How do I get the abstract type from the request?
}
```

I need to be able to create the AbstractType used on the form using only information in the request.

1. Is it possible?
2. How do you do it?

Thanks.

Edit:

Sorry if i wasn't clear enough. in the method "recieveFormRequestAction" i don't know what abstract type i am going to get, so i cant bind the form directly to MyAbstractType.

This action can, in theory, recieve any AbastractType and bind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

1. The method getName() on my forms returned exactly the same name as the Form class name

   ```
   Class MyAbstractType extends AbstractType
     [...]
     public function getName(){
       return "MyAbstractType";
   }
   ```
2. Now i can get the type using the hash on the parameter keys

   ```
   public function myAction(Request $request){
   $parameterKeys = $request->request->keys();
   $formName = $parameterKeys[0];
   ```

Ugly as hell, but i needed a quick solution. Until there is a cleaner one, i'm accepting this.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes
2. Like this:

   ```
   // first, create the very same form
   $form = $this->createForm(new MyAbstractType(), new MyEntity());
   // bind the form with your request
   $form->bind($request);
   // Optional step : validate the form
   if ($form->isValid()) {
       // your object is ready, get it like this:
       $object = $form->getData();
   } else {
        // handle the validation errors.
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the Request object to the form.

```
$form->bind($request);
```

Then you can run things like `$form->isValid()` and `$form->getData()`.